# Date method in JavaScript calendar

Tags: javascript, function, date

I am making a calendar and I want to change the month and the dates can not get it to work. The `change()` function works but if I change the option from December to January the function changes the month but not the dates. My code is below.

The `onchange` function gives the variables that I need as I have checked it with `alert()`. I think the `get_calender()` in my `onchange` function is the problem I but cant find it. How can I change my code to get my desired behaviour?

```
  var d = new Date();
  var year_name =['2014','2015','2016'];
  var month_name = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  var month = d.getMonth(); 
  var year = d.getFullYear(); 
  var first_date = month_name[month] + " " + 1 + " " + year;
  var dagen = new Date(first_date);
  var start = dagen.getDay();
  var day_name = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
  var day_no = day_name[start];
  var days = new Date(year, month +1, 0).getDate();

window.onload = function(){
    var sel = maandgen();
    var ja = jaargen();
    var calendar = get_calendar();
    document.getElementById("calendar-month").appendChild(sel);
    document.getElementById("calendar-year").appendChild(ja);
    document.getElementById("calendar-dates").appendChild(calendar);    
}
function get_calendar(){


  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  //row for the day letters
  for(var c=0; c<=6; c++){
    var day_name = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = day_name[c];
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);
  //create 2nd row
  tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var c;
  for(c=0; c<=6; c++){
    if(c == day_no){
      break;
    }
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = "";
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  var count = 1;
  for(; c<=6; c++){
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML =  "<button onclick= afspraak() id="+c+">"+ count;
    count++;
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);
  //rest of the date rows
  for(var r=3; r<=7; r++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(var c=0; c<=6; c++){
      if(count > days){
        table.appendChild(tr);
        return table;
      }
    for(var i=7;i<=31;i++){
        for(var d=7;d<=31;d++){

      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML =  "<button onclick= afspraak() id="+i+">"+ count;}}//}
      count++;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  return table;
}

function change(maand){

if(maand.value == "0"){
    var first = month_name[0] + " " + 1 + " " + year;
    var dagen = new Date(first);

    var start = dagen.getDay();
    var day_no = day_name[start];
    var days = new Date(year, month +1, 0).getDate();

    get_calendar();
    //alert();
}
}
```

Comment: `new Date(first_date).toDateString();` converts a non–standard string to a Date (which is implementation dependant and unreliable), then back to a string. Not a good idea. Why start with a string over which you have complete control and hand it to a process from which you have no idea what the outcome will be? ;-)

Comment: I have changed the code and moved the todatestring() ;) but i get stuck. It doesnt update the dates when I change the month :(

Comment: @user2570380 i have added all my files to [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4o78xw0b/1/) but it dont work on fiddle on my dreamweaver it work only for month december i cant find why it dont work:(